# Symfony Doctrine sfDoctrinePager and LIMIT

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, pager, paginator

I have a table with 500 users. I need to show the last 100 registred users on my homepage, paginated. So I am using symfony and the pagination with sfDoctrinePager.

## Action:

```
    $query = UserTable::getLast100UsersQuery();
    $pager = new sfDoctrinePager('User', 10);
    $pager->setQuery($query);
    $pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page', 1));
    $pager->init();
```

## Model:

```
    static public function getLast100UsersQuery() {
    return Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')->limit(100);
    }
```

My problem is that the **LIMIT(100)** , in the model, is ignored, and the pagination is for all 500 users. I just want the last 100 users, not all of them.

Thanks in advance for any help guys

Answer (score 0):

I make paging in a bit different way. 
In my model , query is somting like this:

```
public function getLast100UsersQuery($page = null)
     {
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from("User")
        ->limit(100);

       $pager = new sfDoctrinePager('User', 10);
       $pager->setQuery($q);
       $pager->setPage($page, 1);
       $pager->init();

       return $pager;
      }
```

in action i get query :

```
$pager = $this->pager = Doctrine_Core::getTable('user')->getLast100UsersQuery( $request->getParameter('page'));
```

all the tyme i make paging in this way and no have problems :)

Comment: for this case , he need to replays his parameters ,like table name and others . But in my projects i make paginations in this way and work 100%